# Can I Call An AngularJS Function From Selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

Part of my web app has configuration that requires a file upload. This is currently implemented using AngularJS

```
<div ng-file-drop="onFileSelected($files)">Upload Files</div>
```

Dropping a file from the filesystem using Selenium seems nearly impossible and the SendKeys method wont work here as all I have is a `div` and not an `input`.

The alternative seems to be to call the Angular function directly.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can still find an input with `type="file"` in your DOM.

Let's take a look at an example [Angular File Upload DEMO page](http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/). There is a ng-file-upload div that you can drag and drop files onto, but, if you would inspect the DOM, you'll see a *hidden file input element* that is actually responsible for the upload.

What we can do in tests is *make the input visible* so that we can interact with it and send keys to it containing an absolute path to a file to upload. Example code to make the file input visible:

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model=files]"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.overflow = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileInput);

fileInput.sendKeys("/absolute/path/to/a/file");
```

---

Sample code that works for the for the provided fiddle:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("result");

// waiting for the element to appear
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement fileInput = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presencefElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model=file]")));

// making the element visible
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.overflow = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1",
    fileInput);

fileInput.sendKeys("/absolute/path/to/the/file")
```

Once the path is sent to the input, the upload process is triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately not. See this demo for the type of drag and drop upload I am doing http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/s8kc7wg0/219/

Comment: @opticyclic if you would inspect the jsfiddle resulting HTML, you would see hidden inputs at the end of the `iframe`. Here is one of them: `<input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="file" ngf-multiple="false" tabindex="-1" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">`..

Comment: Are you talking about your link  or mine? I cant find that in the jsfiddle. The difference between the two is that your has a submit button and mine does not.

Comment: @opticyclic updated with the working code for the fiddle.

Comment: duuuuddddee! leg-end-dary!

Comment: Work correclty, you have the div, but in the end of the DOM is the `<input type="file" name="documentFiles" >`. You can select this input and use the method sendKeys